# Redirect unauthenticated users in hapi.js only when required

Tags: node.js, authentication, hapi.js

I am using [hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) to protect some routes with user authentication.

```
server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
    password     : process.env.SESSION_COOKIE_PASSWORD,
    cookie       : 'sid',
    clearInvalid : true,
    isHttpOnly   : true,
    isSecure     : true
});
```

Some routes have special behavior if the user is logged in, but should be accessible and function fine either way.

```
{
    method : 'GET',
    path   : '/',
    config : {
        auth : {
            strategy : 'session',
            mode     : 'optional'
        }
    },
    handler(request, reply) {
        if (request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            const { credentials } = request.auth;
            reply(`Hello <pre>${credentials.name}</pre> <a href="/logout">Click here to log out</a>`);
        }
        else {
            reply('Not logged in. <a href="/login">Click here to log in.</a>');
        }
    }
}
```

Some routes are intended only for logged in users and should be inaccessible to everyone else.

```
{
    method : 'GET',
    path   : '/profile',
    config : {
        auth : {
            strategy : 'session',
            mode     : 'required'
        }
    },
    handler(request, reply) {
        const { credentials } = request.auth;
        reply(`This is your private profile: <pre>${JSON.stringify(credentials, null, 4)}</pre> <a href="/logout">Click here to log out</a>`);
    }
}
```

Both of these work perfectly as-is, except that if I visit `/profile` without being logged in, then an ugly `401 Unauthorized` JSON message is displayed. Ideally it would just ask me to log in.

So I go ahead and add `redirectTo : '/login'` on the session strategy. Now `/profile` behaves perfectly and redirects me to login if necessary. Unfortunately, the `/` route does too, even though it is `mode : optional`. The docs do mention that `try` mode behaves this way and I correctly assumed `optional` would as well. However, this seems pretty silly and the setup here is extremely common for web applications.

How are people doing this? I've come up with a few options, none of which I like.

1. Implement redirects in handlers myself, which isn't very clean.
2. Override the plugin options for every `mode : optional` route, which isn't much better.

   ```
   {
       method : 'GET',
       path   : '/',
       config : {
           plugins : {
               'hapi-auth-cookie' : {
                   redirectTo : false
               }
           },
           auth : {
               strategy : 'session',
               mode     : 'optional'
           }
       }
       handler(request, reply) {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. Have two session strategy instances with different configurations. So there would be `session-optional` and `session-required`. Though I would still have to specify the `mode` in each route, which isn't DRY. On top of that, `hapi-auth-cookie` doesn't seem to like being instantiated more than once.